# Reconnect XCode debug console after app exits?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an incredibly frustrating crash that only occurs after I press home button and then go back into my app. But once you hit the home button, XCode's debugger is disconnected and receives no more NSLog messages. Is it possible to reenable NSLog after returning to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when the debugger isn't connected, any output generated via `NSLog` still gets saved, and then you can look at the console log later using the XCode Organizer.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429205/is-there-a-way-to-capture-the-ouput-of-nslog-on-an-iphone-when-not-connected-to-a).