# Viewing the console log in iOS7

Tags: debugging, logging, console, ios7, nslog

Prior to iOS7, if I wanted to view the output log of an app running on an iOS device, I would use one of:

https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/system-console/id431158981?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/console/id317676250?mt=8

However, since upgrading to iOS7, both of these don't seem to be recording the log output of any app on my phone.

Would this be due to a new setting on my phone? Or has iOS7 changed the way in which logging is handled such that these two apps are now broken?

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work anymore. Is there a discussion about the best practice to get around this?

Comment: If you want to read logs only from you own application on iOS device then you can use https://github.com/fins/LSLogViewer library. It will show NSLogs from your own app on device with iOS 7.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We're the creator of System Console -  https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/system-console/id431158981?mt=8

It looks like in iOS7 the sandbox now prevents an app from seeing the logs of other apps. In iOS6 apps could no longer see kernel and system log entries. Now in iOS7 you can only see your own logs. For System Console this is obviously a deal breaker.

I don't see any apps store approved ways of getting around it.

It might be that we have to find a backdoor way of accessing the logs and release the source code to System Console with this method. i.e you build it  yourself.

Chris

Comment: it's really too bad, we were using this excellent App when we had complex issues with our customers. This is really a shame ... Apple is making all its possible to prevent App developpers to actually serve people correctly. I hope you'll find something

Comment: any updates @lyonanderson? Does this means there is no way we can access the console on ios7?

Comment: Well, That's sad. But it's for the best. A I know a bunch of applications that log sensitive data using NSLog.

Comment: Just found out that after all, Chris & co were able to get a new version of System Console approved in to App store (the same link still applies). Now we can see the system console logs live on iphone device with this App - Great stuff!!!

Answer (score 17):

*iOS 8 + Xcode Method*

Within Xcode 6:

In the menu, open Window -> Devices.
Select your device, and there's a little arrow at the bottom:
[image: Arrow icon]

Click this and it will pop open the device console.

*iPhone Configuration Utility Method*

This has stopped working for me since iOS 8 was released, but [evidently *may* work if iTunes is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26042000/220307).

You can do this while plugged into your mac with the iPhone Configuration Utility. Not as portable, but still useful.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

You can select your device on the sidebar, and among other options, one of the tabs is "Console".

This exists for Windows as well: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466

Not quite the same but it works.

Comment: Great advice.  I can see the log now, so good enough for me. :)

Comment: We tried the Windows link, but our users reported this error: "The procedure entry point xmlTextReaderConstName could not be located in the dynamic link library libxml2.dll." Did you have this same problem?

Comment: No, that sounds like they are missing a necessary library. Maybe try a reinstall or manually installing the file (http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/)

Comment: We were using this method up until the new upcoming mobile OS. Apparently not working anymore. Anyone can confirm ?

Comment: Updated my comment; this is now possible with Xcode 6.