# Viewing the console log in new iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

As a follow-up from this question:
[Viewing the console log in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042497/viewing-the-console-log-in-ios7/)

In iOS 6, There were apps to get system console logs directly on the device.

In iOS 7, those apps were not working anymore, we had to use the iPhone Configuration Utility on the Mac or Windows desktop to access the device logs. This was inconvenient but at least we would get the log.

In the upcoming mobile OS people are all waiting for, it seems that this is no longer possible as well, leaving us with no possible way of remotely helping customers on the field.

2 questions:

- Can anyone confirm this ? Is there anything to enable to reactive system console logs ?
- If not, anyone to suggest an alternative method ?

Comment: Get iSyslog: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/isyslog-system-monitoring/id468155763?mt=8
Works also on iOS7 and iOS8. Runs natively on any device (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad). No jailbreaking required.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm this, but I don't think it was ever the right way of helping your customer remotely.

There are a lot of remote logging, bug and crash reporting tool on the market.

- http://try.crashlytics.com
- https://instabug.com
- http://hockeyapp.net/features/
- https://www.testflightapp.com

Or you can use CocoaLumberjack or any other logging framework, save the logs to a file, and attach those files to an email.

- https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack

Or more debugging, you can use this tool, it has a lot of functionality:

- https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX
- and check out [this NSConference video](http://vimeo.com/90423351) for more debugging tips and tricks.

Comment: @Kaszas David sure, console log is the last thing we use, we're using BugSense for remote crash reports and logging but when in Beta, we're still using Console logs for more details. Are you able to get remote console logs from CocoaLumberJack ?

Comment: No you are not. I can't think of too much case when you really need the console log, but please give me an example.
With proper logging I think you can find any bugs, but if you are doing some magic stuff, check out this debugging framework (not for production code): https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX and watch this this NSConference video: http://vimeo.com/90423351. I think you will find this more helpful than reading console logs.

Comment: @DavidKaszas The question was not whether you think it appropriate to get a console log, but HOW to get a console log. Your needs are not the same as other people's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is an App in App Store that allows seeing system console logs on devices with iOS 8.1 or later: https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/system-console/id431158981?mt=8