# iOS 8 devices aren't being recognized by iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: iphone, configuration, ios8, ipcu

With the recent update to iOS 8 I have been unable to load my test devices using the iPhone Configuration Utility.  Devices with iOS 8 are simply not recognized within the program.  When iOS 7 was released there was no required update for the iPCU,  though it did work with iOS 7.  The latest version on Apple's support site (3.6.2) says that it supports up to iOS 6.1.

Does anyone have any insight?  Alternatives?

Comment: Found this tip: https://discussions.apple.com/message/12039431#12039431 (didn't work for me)

Answer (score 6):

Apple deprecated iPhone Configuration Utility, and released Apple Configurator for iOS device administration - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12. However, some features (like managing provisioning profiles stored on mac) are not available in this new tool.

Comment: What about options for windows?

Comment: Sorry, there's no Apple Configurator for Windows.

Comment: Also it's OS X 10.10+ only.

Answer (score 6):

You have to upgrade iTunes and it will work